# spread operator within an useEffect not working

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to update my state within the callback function of `socket.on`. I'm trying to gather all messages within an array, however, the spread operator not working, therefore, it's just updating to the last value (first element).

`console.log`, outputs just the updated first element. What could be the issue?

Thanks

```
const [messageReceived, setMessageReceived] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('receive_message', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setMessageReceived([...messageReceived, data.message]);
            setIsSent(false);
        });
    }, [isSent]);
```

Comment: try `setMessageReceived(prev=>[...prev, data.message]);`

Comment: try logging `messageReceived` inside `useEffect`

Comment: @WebbH, that works, however I'm getting two outputs instead of just one (two same elements) into the array. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using your socket function inside `useEffect` which will only trigger when `isSent` state changes, check whether `isSent` state is correctly changing in your code.

Comment: tried that one too, unfortunately doesnt work.